# What's the best practise of building/dockerizing springBoot application which has a database connection?

Tags: hibernate, docker, spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot application which has the following `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap:something
spring.datasource.username=${USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${PASSWORD}
```

As you can see, it depends on some environmental variables. My final destination is docker image but before that I run `gradle build` task - and it fails, of course, as it cannot find `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` in environmental variables.

Therefore, I would like to split my question into two:

1. Should `gradle test` task, which is executed along with `gradle build`, be trying to test the database connection at all? It does it by default when it tries to bootstrap the spring boot application - that's why my `gradle build` task fails. Somehow I think that's not the best option - as unit tests should not depend on any external factors such as database connection, in my opinion.
2. Is it a good idea to run `gradle build` first and then running `docker build`? Or everything should be done in one go? Then I can at least define environment variables on `docker run`. But then again, I wouldn't want to build docker image without knowing that the build is fine and all test have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions with "is it a good idea" are hard to answer, but I'll try...

1. Most people see unit tests as a way of testing the code, *not* the environment on which that code runs. That's one reason mocks etc. are so popular. So I would make sure your gradle test task only tests "code". 
   There is of course the weirdness that you may want to test your database connection code (as opposed to environment), which is hard to do without connecting to a database.
2. Again, most people have their build step output some kind of package, which they deploy into the Docker container. So I would run your gradle build before the Docker build - and I would include a "smoke test" step to ensure your application boots, and can connect to the database. You may also want to run unit tests that cannot be refactored to not require a database at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your questions:

1. In my humble opinion, in general, `gradle test` should be executed after `gradle build`. Unless your database testing is one of the tests, if you only use it to gather information for your tests, I'd execute `gradle test` after database checking.
2. Yes, it's a good idea to do:

   - First, `docker build`
   - Second, `docker run -e USERNAME=XXXX -e PASSWORD=XXXX...`
   - Third, `gradle build` inside docker.

Comment: 1. So you suggest building it first by excluding the test task, like `gradle build -x test`? And then, when I am in an environment which can reach the database and has all the enrivonment variables (credentials) in place, perform the testing part?

Comment: 2. But what about if I want to make a proper CI/CD pipeline? Isn't it that already built docker image should be assumed as a correct one? Cause if I build it first, then test inside it and it turns out to be failing on tests, I have to remove it. Or it's completely fine and, if something fails, I just build another image with updated code?

Comment: 1. Yes, I would try it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should ask yourself if you really need to bootstrap an entire application for your test. If you have a test that checks if certain methods produce the correct output for a given input that doesn't require database calls, you probably don't need it.

Even when a test requires a database connection, you should ask yourself whether or not it should be the actual database. If you rely on a separate database for your tests, that also means that your entire build process will fail if there's any maintenance on the database. Perhaps it's a better idea to use a separate, in-memory database for testing purposes.

To make that happen, you could add an in-memory database such as HSQLDB to your project as a test dependency:

```
testCompile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
```

After that, you can provide a separate `application-test.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Now you can annotate any test that requires a database connection with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

Even if you don't like an in-memory database for testing purposes, you can still use the approach of using multiple profiles to use a different database configuration for your testing (eg. a hardcoded connection + username/password to a database).